# Chakra UI : How can i change the color of Divider?

Tags: html, reactjs, chakra-ui

I'm trying to change the color of divider while it is not changing

```
<Stack color={'white'} >
           <HStack>
               <Text>Email</Text>
                 <Tag
                   size={'sm'}
                   borderRadius='full'
                   variant='solid'
                   colorScheme='green'>
                    
                   <TagLabel>verified</TagLabel>
                   </Tag>
                 </HStack>
                  <Divider color={'red'} />
           </Stack>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just try to add borderColor on divider.

```
<Stack color={'white'} >
           <HStack>
               <Text>Email</Text>
                 <Tag
                   size={'sm'}
                   borderRadius='full'
                   variant='solid'
                   colorScheme='green'>
                    
                   <TagLabel>verified</TagLabel>
                   </Tag>
                 </HStack>
                  <Divider borderColor={'red'} />
           </Stack>
```